# AngularJs Posting to a WebApi method with dynamic properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My webApi controller code looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public int ValidateUser([FromBody]dynamic credentials)
        {
            try
            {
                string username = credentials.username;
                string password = credentials.password;
                //do stuff
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
                return -1;
            }

            return -1; // not valid user
        }
```

My angular Service looks like this:

```
 getAuthorizationStatus: function () {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            'username': applicationConstants.userName,
                            'password': applicationConstants.userPass
                        },
                        headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
                    }).success(deferred.resolve)
                      .error(deferred.reject);
                    return deferred.promise;
                },
```

I am able to reach the webApi method but no matter how I do this, it always returns an error like this:
{"'object' does not contain a definition for 'username'"}

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ASP.net, but it seems that you are sending JSON data through a "x-www-form-urlencoded;" request.

You should either change 'data: ...' to 'username=,password=', **or** if you want to use JSON, use

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

If the web server is decent, it should detect you content type and interpret it as JSON instead of looking for "form" data.

Also consider using tools such as **curl** (or any webservice allowing you to send arbitrary HTTP requests) to test and understand what is going on.